Is the non-uniform membership problem for sets obtained from 1 by applying affine integer functions P/NP-complete/other?
The question concerns algorithmic complexity of the membership problem for sets obtained from $1$ by applying a fixed number of affine functions. One such example is Klarner-Rado sequence (A002977 in the OEIS). The set $S$ of its members is the least set that contains $1$ and that it closed under application of $2x+1$ and $3x+1$. Consider the following problem: given a number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (written in binary), check if $n \in S$. I am interested in the algorithmic complexity of this problem. Clearly, it is in NP. Is it P/NP-complete/other?
In general, let us fix some affine maps $f_1,\dotsc,f_m$, each of which is of the form $ax+b$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$; let $S$ be the least set containing $1$ and closed under each of $f_i$. What is the complexity of the problem "given $n$, say if $n \in S$"? I'd expect that either

There are $f_1,\dotsc,f_m$, for which this problem is NP-complete OR THAT
For any fixed $f_1,\dotsc,f_m$, there is a polynomial algorithm OR THAT
This is a hard open problem in line with Klarner's conjecture.

Any references would be appreciated.
